# Singleton MFC extension DLL

Tags: dll, mfc, singleton

I declare a singleton on a MFC extension DLL, like this:

```
//header file: SingleTon.h
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CMySingleton
{
public:
  static CMySingleton* Instance()
  {
    if(!singleton)
        singleton = new CMySingleton();
    return singleton;
  }

  int a;

// Other non-static member functions
private:
  CMySingleton() {};                                 // Private constructor
  CMySingleton(const CMySingleton&);                 // Prevent copy-construction
  CMySingleton& operator=(const CMySingleton&);      // Prevent assignment
  virtual ~CMySingleton() {};

  static CMySingleton* singleton;
};

And in a cpp file I code the following line:

CMySingleton* CMySingleton::singleton = NULL;
```

Code 2:

```
CMySingleton *a;

a = CMySingleton::Instance();
```

The problem is when I code "code 2" in a Regular Dll, all works fine, but when I code "code 2" in another MFC extension DLL gives an error:

```
unresolved external symbol "private: static class CMySingleton* CMySingleton::singleton" (?singleton@CMySingleton@@0PAV1@A)
```

I check correctly all the dependencies, via Project Dependencies.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the AFX_EXT_CLASS macro.

```
#ifdef _AFXEXT
    #define AFX_EXT_CLASS       __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define AFX_EXT_CLASS       __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Extension dll defines _AFXEXT and your class is exported, and main app (or a regular dll) doesn't define it so it's imported. But your second extension dll also defines _AFXEXT and your class declaration uses dllimport instead of dllexport and you get a linker error. The solution is to create your own macro for both dlls and use them instead of AFX_EXT_CLASS:

```
#ifdef EXTENSION_ONE
    #define EXT_CLASS_ONE       __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define EXT_CLASS_ONE       __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Create EXTENSION_TWO and EXT_CLASS_TWO for your second dll. Define EXTENSION_ONE only in your first extension dll project, and EXTENSION_TWO only in your second extension dll project.